# How to add the counts of the same number in a for loop and make a lists(Python)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, matplotlib

[image: The data I am using: Analyzing Data and using for loops and lists]B0e.png

I am still relatively new to python. I am trying to do something more complicated. How can I use a for loop or iteration so that I count the same names ranked 1 and add them but also place them into a list format and also place the counted names in a separate list. The reason for this is that I will create a plot, and that I can do but I am stuck on how to separate the total counts of the same name and the names already counted.

Comment: please post part of your data as text in your question and not an image

Answer (score 0):

Using this as example DataFrame:

```
   RANK      NAME
0     1     EMILY
1     1    DANIEL
2     1     EMILY
3     1  ISABELLA
```

You can do this to get the counted names:

```
counted_names = name_file[name_file.RANK == 1]['NAME'].value_counts()
print(counted_names)

EMILY       2
DANIEL      1
ISABELLA    1
```

Answer (score 0):

## pandas.groupby()

To solve any form aggregation in Python, all you need is to crack the groupby Function

For your case if you want to sum over 'Count' for all the unique names and later plot it, use pd.groupby()

Make sure you convert it into a DataFrame first and then apply Groupby Magic

```
name_file = pd.DataFrame(name_file)
name_file.groupby('Name').agg({'Count':'sum'})
```

This gives you the aggregated sum of counts for eaxh unique name in your dataframe

To get the Count of each Name, use the size.reset_index() method below

```
pd.DataFrame(name_file).groupby('Name').size().reset_index()
```

This returns the frequency of occurence of each unique name in the name_file

Hope this helps! Cheers !